# I used select2. but upgraded 4.0.13. and It appeared title

Tags: jquery-select2

I used select2. and upgraded 4.0.13. 
It appeared title.

so, I do

```
if($('.select2-selection__rendered')) {
        $('.select2-selection__rendered').removeAttr('title');
    }
```

in public/app.js

and disappeared title at select2.

but,

It appeared title that It is used title in other page. with title appeared.
Even where you haven't used select2.

why?

I can't style title attribute.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am6HG.png)

In addition, it is a style to display the title in select2. It's a problem.
I want to revert to the original title style.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved.

I do only changed loading order.

jquery -> jquery-ui -> bootstrap

so, displayed basic title style at browser.